# ImageIO.Read(...) returning null, platform-dependent

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, javax.imageio

The following Java snippet correctly returns an image object on an instance of Ubuntu (ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server):

```
URL url = new URL("http://imworld.aufeminin.com/story/20150128/-582643_w1000.jpg");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(conn.getInputStream());
```

When I run the same on AWS Linux, image remains null. For other image URLs both Ubuntu and AWS linux work ok, so this is an example of a JPG for which AWS linux is not working.

Both environments are using the same JVM:

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

vs.

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.5.4.0.53.amzn1-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

I am a total loss to explain the difference in behaviour. Might anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "Both environments are using the same JVM" Not exactly, as one seems to use an IcedTea build, while the other uses a special Amazon build it seems. But I don't see how that should make a difference. Doesn't seem to be anything special about the JPEG file (though it *does* have *666* lines, so it might be a little evil...). I'd say try a debugger.

Comment: Just an idea: Can you print what headers the `HttpURLConnection` actually  sends to the client, to see if there's a difference there, that might prevent images being downloaded from certain servers?